Suppress preliminary output from wolframscript
$ /opt/homebrew/bin/wolframscript  -code "AirTemperatureData[Here,Now] // First"
StringForm[Initializing `1` indices ...., WeatherData]
StringForm[Initializing `1` indices ...., WeatherData]
75.9

How do i prevent those StringForm lines from showing in the output so I only receive the “75.9” answer?

That would also suppress the ending output. I did try the following, which yielded the same result:
wolframscript -code "x = First[AirTemperatureData[Here,Now]]; x"
StringForm[Initializing `1` indices ...., WeatherData]
StringForm[Initializing `1` indices ...., WeatherData]
77.

